# Replacing tag content with html string

Tags: node.js, dom, xmldom

I have the following xml:

```
<foo><toReplace/></foo>
```

I want to replace `<toReplace/>` tag with the following string:

```
"<b>bar</b>"
```

How can I do that?

Right now I have the following code:

```
var xml = "<foo><toReplace/></foo>";
var parser = new dom.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
parser.getElementsByTagName("toReplacce")[0].textNode = "<b>bar</b>";
console.log(parser.toString()); // "<foo>&lt;b>bar&lt;/b>"
```

The problem is that is escapes HTML. How can I replace the content with the HTML string here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use the module from npm

```
var unescape = require('unescape');

console.log(unescape(parser.toString()))
```

When I tested your code there is a small typo:  (toReplacce instead of toReplace)

```
var dom = require('xmldom');

var xml = "<foo><toReplace/></foo>";
var parser = new dom.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
var a = parser.getElementsByTagName("toReplace")[0];
//console.dir(a);
a.textvalue = "<b>bar</b>";
console.log(parser.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: But I don't want to unescape the whole XML. I only don't want to unescape the part I replace.

Comment: Have you tried parser.getElementsByTagName("toReplacce")[0].content = ...

Comment: content is undefined. It's the Element object.

Comment: try also the innerHTML .   parser.getElementsByTagName("toReplacce")[0].innerHTML =

Comment: Nope, doesn't exist as well

Comment: Does the textvalue work for you? I can't see the output. Thank you for testing the code.